# How to set crossover probability in neat-python implementaiton?

Tags: python, configuration, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, neat

I cannot find any option in configuration file. How to set this probability? I have gone through config description file also https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html and there is no such option.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it is this

```
survival_threshold
The fraction for each species allowed to reproduce each generation. This defaults to 0.2.
```

but I feel the default is low. Would have expected something around 0.7.

So put

```
[DefaultReproduction]
survival_threshold = 0.7 (or whatever you want to set it to)
```

in your configuration file

Comment: survival threshold with some value say 0.7 selects only 70% of best fit individuals from current population. Now these selected individuals are allowed to reproduce using crossover and mutation. Config file has mutation probability but no option for crossover probability.

Comment: Yes. That means 70% of those solutions are allowed to mate using crossover, I believe.